# Testing async functions that fetch data using jquery with Jest

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, jestjs

I am trying to test an async function that fetches data from a json file and stores it in a variable

The function I am trying to test (present in registration.js):

```
async function readJSONFile(url) {
    const data = await $.getJSON(url);
    return data;
}

let returnedData = await readJSONFile(testURL);

module.exports = readJSONFile;
```

How can I create a test file using jest in order to test this function?

I tried this code for testing but for some reason, it is not reading the main javascript file

```
const readJSONFile = require("../JS/registration.js").readJSONFile;


test("check if the data is retrieved", async () => {
    const testData = {
        "courseName" : {
            "instrName" : "profName",
            "location" : "classLocation",
            "timings" : "classTimings"
        }
    }

    const data = await  $.getJSON(testURL);
    expect(data).toBe(testData)
});
```

The error:

```
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
```

Project Structure:

```
| Jest Testing
    | registration.test.js

| JS
    | registration.js
```

Answer (score 0):

`require` expects a **module** path and returns the `exports` object.

You've appended the property name to the path.

You've also failed to account for the two JS files being in different directories.

```
const readJSONFile = require("../JS/registration.js").readJSONFile;
```

Comment: I have updated the code but got a new error